# How to search character black triangle (▼ or ►) in NSString?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, replace, character

I want to change the black triangle (▼ or ►) with white space. How could I search that character in NSString so I can change it with white space?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you not just use the following?

```
[myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"►" withString:@" "];
[myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"▼" withString:@" "];
```

Comment: yes, thank you, i was wrong, i think it same with a black diamond question mark, i cant replace it into a character i want, before
Thank you james

Comment: Yea, it's clearly not a standard ascii character, so you'll have to ensure that the string that you're dealing with, or the reader you're using, supports that character. A standard NSString has no problem with it though. :)

Comment: Worth noting that doing that does make you dependent on the character encoding of the source file, since it is no longer ASCII text; newer versions of the developer tools support UTF-8 encoded source for this purpose, though you may still sometimes need to pay attention to encoding issues (e.g. with version control, e-mail and so on).